# Сортировка коллекций

Tags: java, сортировка

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать задачу:
Имеется список объектов `List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();`
Требуется его отсортировать - последний записаный объект распечатать сверху.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода ..... также стоит добавить из чего состоит класс `Contact` (структура), а также по каким полям надо сортировать этот сложный объект

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сделайте класс `Contact` расширяющим интерфейс `Comparable`, и реализуйте по своему усмотрению метод `compareTo`. Далее сортировать коллекцию будет очень просто - `Collections.sort(contacts)`;